# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, django-urls

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de gestion de personal a una empresa usando django 1.11 y python 2.7, todo funciona bien hasta que en las url trato de hacer una llamada pk a una tabla de otro modelo incluido en la aplicacion, les dejo mis view.py, url.py y la lista de el error.

PD: se que el error esta en la url donde llamo la pk, pues sin el todo funciona bien.

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from empleados.models import Empleado
from catalogos.models import Persona


# Create your views here.
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    empleados = Empleado.objects.all()
    return render(request, "empleados/index.html",{ 'empleados' : empleados})
def detalle_empleado(request, id_persona):
    dato = get_object_or_404(Empleado, pk=id_persona)
    personas = Persona.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('empleados/artistas.html', {'dato': dato, 'personas': personas})
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index_empleados'),
    url(r'^(?P<id_empleados>\d+)$', 'empleados.views.detalle_empleado', name='perfil_empleado'),

]
```

error

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000004C46BA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Roly\Desktop\Desarrollo ALACERO\Desarrollo ALACERO\recursoshumanos-master\recursoshumanos-master\recursoshumanos\urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    url(r'^empleados/', include('empleados.urls')),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Roly\Desktop\Desarrollo ALACERO\Desarrollo ALACERO\recursoshumanos-master\recursoshumanos-master\empleados\urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    url(r'^(?P<id_empleados>\d+)$', 'empleados.views.detalle_empleado', name='perfil_empleado'),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.18-py2.7.egg\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 85, in url
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice el mensaje, la vista debe ser un callable (es decir, una función). En tu caso, para tu segunda URL estás usando una cadena:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index_empleados'),
    url(r'^(?P<id_empleados>\d+)$', 'empleados.views.detalle_empleado', name='perfil_empleado'),
]
```

Si te das cuenta, para el primer caso (`index_empleados`) ya estás usando un callable (que en este caso es la función misma). Intenta hacer lo mismo para tu URL `perfil_empleado`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index_empleados'),
    url(r'^(?P<id_empleados>\d+)$', views.detalle_empleado, name='perfil_empleado'),    
]
```

Comment: gracias broth tu respuesta ha sido de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar quitandole la comilla simple a 'empleados.views.detalle_empleado'. Además en la url sustituyendo

```
url(r'^(?P<id_empleados>\d+)$', ...etc.
```

Por

```
url(r'^(?P<id_persona>\d+)$', ...etc.
```